# Connection JDBC SQL Error

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, jsp

This is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language= "java" %>
<%@ page contentType= "text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import= "java.sql.*" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

    <head>
        <title>Lettura di un database con JSP</title>       
    </head>


    <body>

        <h1>Connessione al database</h1>

            <%
                Connection conn;
                Statement st;
                ResultSet rs;
                String dat;
            try{
                Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ).newInstance();                 // crea un'istanza del driver e la inizializza, affinché il Driver Manager stabilisca una connessione con MySQL
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                out.println("<p>ERROR1</p>");
                }
                try{
                conn= DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://94.94.216.82:8080/dale14/dale14_mobshop", "dale14", "ViEh8Udr" );

                st = conn.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery( "SELECT Nome FROM clienti" );

                while( rs.next() ){                                                     // alla prima "next" andiamo sul primo rigo della tabella
                    dat = rs.getString( "Nome" );                                       // ottiene il dato, che è di tipo stringa
                    out.println( "<tr><td>" + dat + "</td></tr>" );                     // stampa a video
                }

                st.close();                                                             // viene chiuso anche il ResultSet
                conn.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException ex){

                out.println ( "<P><PRE>" );
                while (ex != null) {
                out.println("Message:   " + ex.getMessage ());
                out.println("SQLState:  " + ex.getSQLState ());
                out.println("ErrorCode: " + ex.getErrorCode ());
                ex = ex.getNextException();
                out.println("");        
                }}

            %>

    </body>

</html>
```

And this the error:

> Message:   Communications link failure
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   SQLState:  08S01
>   ErrorCode: 0

I do not understand why!:(

Answer (score 0):

Because the SQLState: 08S01 error is a network connection problem.

You need to make sure that:

1. The database is running AND listening to the port specified
2. You have permissions to connect to the database
3. You don't have any firewall issues that may be interfering with your connection.

Also consider the size of your DB. If it is very large, you might have a problem.

In addition, you might either need to change your driver (to jTDS possibly) or update to the most recent version of SQL Server.

Also look into the [System Requirements for JDBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx)

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you please mark it up and select the green check mark for me? :D Thank you @user3645662